# Finish editing UITextField on back button tap

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have 2 controllers inside NavigationController. First pushes the second one to the stack and user can interact with the text field there. Then (in one scenario) user will tap on back button to be taken to the previous screen. Assuming that loading of second one is 'heavy', so I will be keeping only one instance of it once it is needed.

**Expected:**
I would like to have keyboard hidden once back button is pressed.

**Actual:** 
First responder keeps being restored when I go back to the second for the second time. How to prevent that? Resigning first responder also doesn't do the trick there...

**Problem demo:**
https://gitlab.com/matrejek/TestApp

**Major code parts:**

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    var child: UIViewController = {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "child")
        return vc
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func onButtonTap(_ sender: Any) {
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(child, animated: true)
    }
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Swap the lines in `viewWillDisappear()`? It is not required to call `super` within an override - if it's needed, you can call it after performing "disappear" tasks.

Answer (score 3):

This does seem odd --- and it seems like your approach *should* work.

Apparently (based on quick testing), since you are not allowing the Navigation Controller to release the SecondVC, the text field is remaining "active."

If you add this to `SecondViewController`, it will prevent the keyboard from "auto re-showing" the next time you navigate to the controller - not sure it will be suitable for you, but it will do the job:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

---

**Edit: Jan 25 2020**

Based on new comments, yes, this *seems* to be a bug.

My previous work-around answer worked -- sort of. The result was the keyboard popping up and then disappearing on subsequent pushes of `child`.

Following is a better work-around. We have `SecondViewController` conform to `UITextFieldDelegate` and add a BOOL class var / property that will prevent the text field from becoming first responder. Comments should be clear:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    var child: UIViewController = {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "child")
        return vc
    }()

    @IBAction func onButtonTap(_ sender: Any) {
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(child, animated: true)
    }
}

// conform to UITextFieldDelegate
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    // bool var to prevent text field re-becoming first responder
    // when VC is pushed a second time
    var bResist: Bool = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // assign text field delegate
        textField.delegate = self
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        // view has appeared, so allow text field to become first responder
        bResist = false
    }

    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        return !bResist
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        // end editing on this view
        view.endEditing(true)

        // we want to resist becoming first responder on next push
        bResist = true
    }
}
```

Comment: I have recently struggled with this issue too. My own investigations have shown that the problem is perhaps not as simple: you can set the call to `endEditing` inside a call to `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` with some arbitrary value for the delay and the keyboard will be dismissed. It looks glitchy and probably a kludge, but no less glitchy looking as the solution offered. My suspicion is that this is actually a view lifecycle timing issue. Indeed, as DonMag noted, not retaining a reference to the other VC will solve the issue.

Comment: Also, if you print the number of view controllers in the navigation stack you can indeed confirm that the second VC is no longer there, and you can even use `CFGetRetainCount(_:)` to see that the retain count increments after push, then decrements after pop. I think this issue possibly needs the attention of Apple.

Comment: I submitted a bug report to Apple.

Comment: @MH175 - yep, issue still exists with Xcode 11 / iOS 13, so I would also call it a bug. I've edited my answer with a better work-around that prevents the "glitchy" keyboard show/hide problem,