# UINavigationController back button doesn't end UITextField editing

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitextfield

Pressing a `UINavigationController` back button does not permanently end editing on a `UITextField` on a child view controller if the navigation controller maintains a reference to its children. Pushing the child view controller back onto the stack immediately causes the text field to resume editing, causing the keyboard to pop back up. You must manually call `popViewController()`.

---

Update: Looks like this questions has been asked:
[Finish editing UITextField on back button tap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47718291/finish-editing-uitextfield-on-back-button-tap)

---

Steps to reproduce (presented in XCode playground style for simplification)

1. Define a view controller with a single text field, and inform the textfield to end editing when the view disappears

```
class TextFieldViewController: UIViewController {

    let textField = UITextField()

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        self.textField.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

2. Define a navigation controller which maintains a reference to 2 instances of the view controller.

```
class MyNavigationController: UINavigationController {
    let textFieldVC1 = TextFieldViewController()
    let textFieldVC2 = TextFieldViewController()
}
```

3. Create the navigation controller, and set the 1st child VC as root.

```
let myNavVC = MyNavigationController()
myNavVC.setViewControllers([myNavVC.textFieldVC1], animated: false)
```

4. Push the 2nd VC

```
myNavVC.pushViewController(myNavVC.textFieldVC2, animated: true)
```

5. Tap the text field in the second VC to call up the keyboard
6. Press the navigation controller back button: `endEditing(_:)` is called, and the keyboard is dismissed
7. Push the second VC back onto the stack

```
myNavVC.pushViewController(myNavVC.textFieldVC2, animated: true)
```

Result: the keyboard pops up again and the text field calls `textFieldDidBeginEditing(_:)`.

I have tried to move the call to `endEditing(_:)` into various view controller lifecycle methods to no effect, (i.e. `willMove(toParent:)`, `didMove(toParent:)`, etc.). I have also tried adding additional calls to `resignFirstResponder()`.

---

Complete Code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var navVC: UINavigationController!
    let textFieldVC1 = TextFieldViewController()
    let textFieldVC2 = TextFieldViewController()

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        self.navVC = segue.destination as? UINavigationController
        navVC!.setViewControllers([self.textFieldVC1], animated: false)
    }
}

class TextFieldViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    let textField = UITextField()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.addSubview(self.textField)
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        self.textField.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 64, width: 200, height: 48)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

}
```

---

Storyboard:

[image: Storyboard File]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the artifice here:

```
class MyNavigationController: UINavigationController {
    let textFieldVC1 = TextFieldViewController()
    let textFieldVC2 = TextFieldViewController()
}
```

You are now retaining references to both view controllers, so neither of them can ever go out of existence. That is not how a navigation controller is supposed to work; you've broken the whole view controller architecture. When we pop from a view controller, it should *go out of existence*, and this would solve the problem you are having. But your child view controllers can *never* go out of existence because you are retaining them here.

> if the navigation controller maintains a reference to its children

Ooooo, so you already *knew* this was the problem! Excellent. So the solution is simple: Don't Do That. It's just wrong, and as you can see, it's messing you up.

(I don't know *why* you were doing that, or even why you see fit to subclass UINavigationController, which is almost always a bad idea. Perhaps you were trying to solve some more interesting problem; maybe you should ask about that problem.)

---

Okay, so now that you've shown some real code and explained what's really going on (embedded navigation controller), I was able to reproduce the phenomenon, but of course if you manage your view controllers in the normal way, it doesn't arise. It looks like you are creating these extra instance properties simply as a convenient way to refer to your view controllers. Solution: use computed properties instead. I rewrote like this, and the problem went away (I didn't need to add a Pop button because the Back button is present and does the same thing):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var navVC: UINavigationController {
        return self.children[0] as! UINavigationController
    }
    var textFieldVC1 : TextFieldViewController? {
        return self.navVC.children[0] as? TextFieldViewController
    }
    var textFieldVC2 : TextFieldViewController? {
        guard self.navVC.children.count > 1 else { return nil }
        return self.navVC.children[1] as? TextFieldViewController
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let button1 = UIButton(type: .system)
        button1.setTitle("Push", for: .normal)
        button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(doPush), for:.primaryActionTriggered)
        button1.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 150, width: 100, height: 30)
        self.view.addSubview(button1)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let navVC = segue.destination as? UINavigationController
        navVC!.setViewControllers([TextFieldViewController()], animated: false)
    }

    @objc func doPush() {
        self.navVC.pushViewController(TextFieldViewController(), animated: true)
        print(self.textFieldVC1 as Any) // proving it works
        print(self.textFieldVC2 as Any) // proving it works
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. The NavVC subclass was just a demo for simplification. The problem I was trying to solve was propagating changes through all child controllers. OK- this does fix it. But is this true for all scenarios, not just NavVCs? What about a ViewModel which owns various subscreens and populates the UI as necessary. The ViewModel can't own the child views? It seems wasteful to recreate a complex UI every time I need it again.

Comment: (1) OK, propagating changes thru all child controllers is an interesting problem, but that's not how to do it. You have a reference to them; they are the navigation controller's `children` and you can get that at any time, or (better) use a broadcast or pub-sub mechanism. (2) No you have it exactly backwards; what's wasteful is to let a view controller, a heavyweight object carrying with it a _really_ heavyweight object (its view), live a moment longer than it needs to. A popped view controller should be permitted to die in just about every case.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks, Matt. One final clarification. Are you referring only to NavVCs? What about the case of a TabBarVC that needs to flip between multiple complex VCs? Or, forget a TabBar, even a single, central MainView that swaps in/out different screens? Seems very heavy to destroy and repopulate on every screen change.

Comment: A tab bar controller is not comparable; it _does_ maintain all if its children simultaneously. But that is not what a navigation controller does. The usual use case for a navigation controller is create-and-push, then later pop-and-release.

Comment: I'm not sure it's the complete picture. If you retain both VCs you may call `endEditing` then press back. It works. But, as described, you can't press back, wait for `viewWillDisappear` and then call `endEditing`. In both cases I am retaining the childVCs and in both cases I am calling `endEditing`. This seems like some kind of view lifecycle timing issue. You can subclass `UINavigationController` and override `popViewController` and add a call to `self.view.endEditing(_:)`. It works.

Comment: No the navigation controller is embed inside a container view. It's like a sidebar. I will add the storyboard.

Comment: No, I don't necessarily need a reference to the navigation controller, I could always just access it through `textFieldVC1.navigationController`.  It's simply convenient for me have references to all the view controllers I am working with. I have tried both and in both cases the issue is still there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206617/discussion-between-matt-and-mh175).